# Fixing a table row as input in a formula when copying

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hello

when copying a formula whilst maintaining a reference cell, one can use the $ sign. I'm using a formula where an entire table column is a source of input. When copying sed formula to the adjacent cell, the source column also shifts to the adjacent column.

How can I keep the original column as input?

[image: In the image I would like to keep the column 'datum' in table Tabel13867 as source]

Thanks!

Comment: Which data changed? Table13867[datum] or Total!XX?

Comment: In tabel 13867 i want to use the data in the column [datum]. When copying the formula to the adjacent cell, the formula changes to the column next to [datum]. How can I avoid this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To make structured references absolute you need to double up the field name.

`tabel13867[datum]`

Would become:

`tabel13867[[datum]:[datum]]`